# Convert Hibernate Criteria to JPA CriteriaQuery

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria, criteriaquery

I'm looking for a solution to "easily" convert Hibernate Criteria code to JPA Criteria Query code without re-writing all the stuff one-to-one. Is it possible to convert the Hibernate Criteria to an SQL query and then reuse it with the JPA Criteria Query? Any other solutions are welcome.

To be more specific, I have a complex method returning a Hibernate Criteria object. We are looking to use only JPA but this method is too sensitive to refactor with the time I have right now. So it would be nice to find an efficient way to "convert" this Criteria to be reused by a JPA Criteria Query.